# Query to find records between specific time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query to get data between specific time period. I want to select data between 23:00 to 03:00 in every day from 2019-11-01 to 2019-12-01.

I wrote a query like below,

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(DAY, EnteredDate) AS PerDate,
    COUNT(Item) AS ItemCount,
    ItemCategory
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    EnteredDate BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2012-12-01' AND 
    CAST(EnteredDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '23:00:00' and '03:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(EnteredDate), ItemCategory
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(DAY, EnteredDate)
```

Can anyone please help me for some query which I can use?

Comment: Hi @UDAYA, please share with us data type of the column EnteredDate ? Thanks!

Comment: EnteredDate [datetime]

Comment: I want get data between 11.00pm  to 03.00am of next day.

Comment: Please can you show us some example of data (3-5 rows of data to start with and 3-5 rows how it should look as result )

Comment: Dear VBoka, 
I want to get category wise Item count from 11.00pm to 03.00am(Next day). 

Date  Category ItemCount
2019-11-01  Cate01  25
2019-11-01 cate02  35
2019-11-01 cate03  10
2019-11-02  Cate01  45
2019-11-02 cate02  80
2019-11-02 cate03  05

Comment: Dear @UDAYA here is a DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7025a2752a75372b42bd535708578e75
fill this demo with data (insert data into demo table). And then go to your question, click edit and insert that demo and expeced results in your question. My answer below is the best I can do from the info you have given.

Comment: Hi @UDAYA, it would be a nice thing from your side to comment answers you have received for the help you asked. People invest some time to try to help and this is least you can do. Also, except comment you can give some answer a vote up if it helped you in any way and you can accept an answer if it is correct. If you do not know how do ask.

Comment: Hi @VBoka, I am really very sorry for the delay responding to answers i have received. you gave me a great support. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want becuas there is no example data but do comment if something is wrong.

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY, EnteredDate) AS PerDate
       , COUNT(Item) AS ItemCount
       , ItemCategory 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE EnteredDate BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-12-01' 
AND  (DATEPART(HOUR, EnteredDate) in (23, 00, 01, 02)
or CAST(EnteredDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '03:00:00')
GROUP BY DATEPART(Day, EnteredDate)
         , ItemCategory
ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY, EnteredDate) ;
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f9a7520f1e94541f776bd78a50a287d)

I do not know what the OP wants, I try to guess one more time with this:

```
SELECT cast(EnteredDate as date)
       , ItemCategory 
       ,COUNT(Item) AS ItemCount
FROM MyTable 
WHERE EnteredDate BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-12-01' 
AND  (DATEPART(HOUR, EnteredDate) in (23, 00, 01, 02)
or CAST(EnteredDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '03:00:00')
GROUP BY cast(EnteredDate as date)
         , ItemCategory
ORDER BY cast(EnteredDate as date)
         , ItemCategory;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36c604e4bfc3a1905ffee08f0d31ed69)

Comment: Hi, that should fix the first issue but you will miss times greater than 23:59:59 and less than 00:00:01.

Comment: What about '11.04.2019 00:00:00.500'?

Comment: Hi @cabbagetreecustard, again, you are correct... Updated it again...

Comment: That works OK, I would update the second part of the OR clause to equal 03:00:00 but it won't return the wrong result.

Comment: @UDAYA I have updated my answer one more time...Hope this is it...

Comment: Hi VBoka /cabbagetreecustard, Thank you very much, i got the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have a time that exceed midnight.  I imagine that you want to keep "shifts" together, so the times from 11:00 p.m. are assigned to the next day.

If so, add an hour and use that for the logic:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY, v.effective_date) AS PerDate,
       COUNT(*) AS ItemCount,
       ItemCategory
FROM MyTable t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEADD(hour, 1, t.EnteredDate))) v(effective_date)
WHERE v.effective_date >= '2019-11-01' AND
      v.effective_date < '2012-12-01' AND 
      CAST(EnteredDate AS TIME) NOT BETWEEN '03:00:00' and '23:00:00'
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, v.effective_date), ItemCategory
ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY, v.effective_date), ItemCategory
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, there is something wrong with this v and open bracket in this part of the code: `(VALUES (DATEADD(hour, 1, t.EnteredDate)) v(effective_date)`

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you .

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(DAY, EnteredDate) AS PerDate,
    COUNT(Item) AS ItemCount,
    ItemCategory
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE,EnteredDate) BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2012-12-01' AND 
    CAST(EnteredDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '23:00:00' and '03:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(DAY, EnteredDate) , ItemCategory
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(DAY, EnteredDate)
```

Comment: This does not return anything.

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, this does not return anything. Thank you.